# Как редактировать json-файл через SSH на сервере с помощью Python и выводить данные на HTML-сайте?

Tags: python, html, json, ssh

Мне нужно постоянно на протяжении ~1 часа редактировать json-файл и на протяжении этого времени выводить содержимое этого файла на HTML-сайт используя Python. Пытался пока что только редактировать файл через FTP/SFTP но ничего не получилось.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Публикуя вопрос, вы уже признаете, что "ничего не получилось" ;) Вопрос должен включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и ***минимальный код для её воспроизведения***. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так, использую библиотеки [paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html) и [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

```
import paramiko, json, time

def ssh_json_edit(ssh_port, ssh_host, ssh_user, ssh_psw, remote_json, duration, sleep):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ssh_host, ssh_port, ssh_user, ssh_psw)

    local_json = remote_json.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]  # 'file.json'
    t0 = t = time.monotonic()
    with ssh.open_sftp() as sftp:
        while (t - t0) < duration:  # на протяжении ~1 часа
            sftp.get(remote_json, local_json)  # скачать с ssh на диск

            with open(local_json) as f:
                json_data = json.load(f)  # читать с диска
            json_data['cat'] = 'new_cat'  # что-то редактировать в json
            with open(local_json, "w") as f:
                json.dump(json_data, f)  # сохранить на диск

            sftp.put(local_json, remote_json)  # загрузить обратно на ssh
            time.sleep(sleep)
            t = time.monotonic()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ssh_json_edit(
        ssh_port=22,
        ssh_host='192.168.1.1',
        ssh_user='username',
        ssh_psw='password',
        remote_json='usr/www/html/file.json',
        duration=3600,
        sleep=15,
    )
```